# Is it possible to pass data from node js to frontend js and not to html?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to pass data (array) from node.js backend to frontend JS to process it there. I don't want to pass data directly to backend-served html file because I'd like to keep it clean and don't want to do any loops there etc.

My backend part looks like this:

```
app.get("/search-db", function (req, res) {
    const term = req.query.term;
    findInDb(term);
    res.redirect('/search', {
        searchResults: searchResults,
    });
})

async function findInDb(query) {
    const collection = await getDbCollection();
    await collection.find().forEach((item) => {
        console.log(item.artist);
        if (item.artist.includes(query) || item.name.includes(query)) {
            searchResults.push(item);
        }
    })
}
```

Is this possible or do I have to clutter my html and use loop there to process passed results?

Comment: A server cannot send data to the client without the client requesting it. The client should fetch the data.

Comment: The client JS should use AJAX to request the data.

Comment: Your web page should use AJAX to make the /search-db API request to your server. Your server route handler should fetch the results from the DB, then invoke `res.send(..)` to send a JSON response back to the client, rather than `res.redirect(...)` to redirect the client to a new page. Also, unrelated, your `findInDb` function should return the search results instead of placing them in a global variable (searchResults). Example [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/node-express-server-rest-api).

Comment: @jarmod I actually use just form to generate URL with query parameter and use req.query to get this query param, then use it to search db. So I need to start with fetch and find the way to send query parameter with fetch?

Comment: Yes, collect the data you need in the web page and then use fetch, rather than doing your typical POST. You can issue POST or GET (or other) with fetch, as you need to.

Comment: @jarmod thanks a lot, I managed to do it. Now I understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web page can use AJAX via [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to make the `/search-db` API request to your server. Your server route handler should fetch the results from the DB, then invoke [res.send()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) to send a JSON response back to the client, rather than [res.redirect()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect) to redirect the client to a new page.

Example: [How to create a REST API with Express.js in Node.js](https://www.robinwieruch.de/node-express-server-rest-api)

Also, unrelated, your `findInDb` function should return the search results instead of placing them in a global variable (`searchResults`).